Export to Excel function returns blank page
When I select the "Export to Excel" function all I get is a blank page. Same applies to the other options as well , for example Print to PDF.
Any clues?
Running Joomla 4.4.8 ,  CiviCRM 5.76.2 , PHP 8.2.23

Sounds like a php fatal error. Check the webserver logs (e.g. apache, nginx, etc)
